# ListObjects not recognised in office 2010

Tags: vba

I am pasting this code from Microsoft VBA.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh273483%28v=office.14%29.aspx

```
Set lo = ListObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
 Source:=Range("A1:F13"), _
 XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
lo.Name = "SampleData"
```

I want to learn about the styles of tables. VBA says that ListObjects variable not found.

I am using 2010. How can it be possible that i just copy paste and it doesn't work?

any help would be appreciate.

many thanks

Comment: tbl.Cell(1, 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=60, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone this is also not working. setwidth not found. why is not finding what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are coding in a standard module you have to explicitly qualify the `Worksheet` object, like for instance:

```
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
 Source:=Range("A1:F13"), _
 XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
```

but you can use whatever valid `Worksheet` reference like `Worksheets("MySheetName")`

Comment: @JohnColeman I also tested it in my Excel 2010 before writing my answer. Without explicit worksheet reference I got 1) a "Variable Not Defined" compile error highlighting `ListObjects` 2) a "Object required" runtime error 424 when typing `ListObjects.Count` in the Immediate Window 3) Both errors vanished at adding explicit worksheet reference.   While it's true that OP's link referred to VBA, I was misleaded by the **VB** tag in the code pane that is usually associated with VB.Net. Anyhow the link I provided shows explicit worksheet reference, although says nothing about it being compulsory.

Comment: @JohnColeman, leave the down vote: the original answer ought to be more accurate

Comment: But the answer as edited is good, and will probably help OP. Downvotes on answers aren't punitive but instead should trigger a needed improvement, as happened with your answer, so +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. i would have never found it... but i still can not solve my problem. i set a tbl as table, and i am trying to use "tbl.tablestyle = ActiveWorkbook.TableStyles(i)" why it's not working? could someone please give the commands for office2010 to change the tablestyle of a table in powerpoint, not in excel. should i use listobjects or i can do it with the table object?

thanks

Comment: ppPres.Slides(NumSlide).tbl.tablestyle = ppPres.Slides(NumSlide).Shapes.TableStyles(i)

that's what i am trying, i know it's pretty weak... sorry. any help? i would like to change format in powerpoint 2010 through vba

Comment: Your _original_ question was actually about an error while setting a "Table" in *Excel*. Now you're putting in a *PowerPoint* issue. This is a new issue and you should make a new post. While you may want to accept my answer as the solution to your _original_ post. Thank you!

Comment: @Albert, I saw you made the new post. How about closing this one?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this forum, i didn't know that i have to accept answer. I marked the check next to your answer, i hope it's enough. I am sorry, i don't know how to close this post. How can I do it? Could you please help me with the other post? regarding managing the size of a text in a powerpoint table in 2010 VBA.

Comment: You checked correctly and it's enough since this also _closes_ the post in that people now know this question has been solved and are able to locate the chosen answer. As for PowerPoint, sorry but I'm not a user of it so can't help you with it. But I'm quite sure people here will guide you to achieve your goal, just detail properly your background, follow their pieces of advice and give proper feedback out of your efforts